# Как сделать так, чтобы картинки не переворачивались при выводе из бд

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Картинки вывожу в Image, ListView и DataGrid. Некоторые выводятся нормально, некоторые перевёрнуто.

Вот, например,вывод в Image:

```
            var pict = from Map in Fields1Entities.GetContex().Map where Map.Name == 
            "Флюсовые известняки" select Map;
            var bit = pict.First().Picture;
         
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bit))
            {

                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();
                img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                img.StreamSource = ms;
                img.EndInit();
                picture.Source = img;

            }
```

Запрос на добавление картинки в бд

```
  SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(Bulk 'путь к картинке', Single_Blob)as Image23)
```

Comment: А как картинки заносятся в БД? Может, там проблема?

Comment: Заносите картинки в бд нормально и не будет ничего перворачиваться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(Bulk 'путь к картинке', Single_Blob)as Image23)

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях, редактируйте вопрос.